Accessing an SQL database hosted in Azure from a Windows app
I've created a Windows-based application (C#, .NET, Windows Forms) which communicates with an SQL database hosted on Azure.
This is all working fine, but the problem is that every time a new installation takes place, I need to add a new opening in the Azure firewall for the new site's IP address, which is starting to become a pain.
I realise it's probably a silly question, but is there any way to get the app to communicate with the Azure database without needing to add an exception to the firewall every time there is a new site?
At the moment, I'm forced to create a new rule in the Azure firewall for every new site. It would be nice if there was some way to avoid having to do this.

You can add a range 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255

Which SQL database? (The  tag is for the SQL language.)

Peter - How much of a security risk is that?

Jarlh - My apologies, I realise now that the  tag wasn't applicable for this question, have removed it now. For the record, it's a Microsoft Azure SQL Database.


I'm forced to create a new rule in the Azure firewall for every new site. It would be nice if there was some way to avoid having to do this.

To resolve the above issue, you can create a firewall rule with a start IP of  0.0.0.0  and an end IP of  255.255.255.255  in the networking tab of Azure SQL Server, as shown below:

Then, you will be able to connect Azure SQL Database to your app without adding IP addresses for every new site, as shown below:

Alternatively, you can use a  Private Endpoint. For more information, you can refer to this  SO answer.
